# Rails: NameError: uninitialized constant OrderItem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

**models/order_item.rb**

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order 
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**models/order.rb**

```
 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base   
     has_many :order_item
 end
```

Now, I test those by using `rails console`. When I typed `OrderItem`, it threw

```
NameError: uninitialized constant OrderItem
```

### Update

I did this in `rails console`

```
2.1.3 :021 >   reload!
Reloading...
 => true 
2.1.3 :022 > Order
 => Order(id: integer, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, status: integer) 
2.1.3 :023 > Item
 => Item(id: integer, status: integer, name: string, price: integer, descript: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, cover_file_name: string, cover_content_type: string, cover_file_size: integer, cover_updated_at: datetime, cate_id: integer) 
2.1.3 :024 > User
 => User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 
2.1.3 :025 > OrderItem
NameError: uninitialized constant OrderItem
    from (irb):25
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@rails416/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Coda/Desktop/code/ruby_pra/shop/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Coda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NameError: uninitialized constant OrderItem

The ***association name*** for `has_many` should be `plural`, so change `has_many :order_item` to `has_many :order_items` in `order.rb`

```
#order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :order_items #plural
end
```

***Update:***

Looking into your code on **github**, there is a ***space*** between `order_item` and `.rb` i.e., (`order_item .rb`) in the ***filename***(`app/models/order_item .rb`). Change it to `order_item.rb`

Comment: I modified that, and I also check others `has_many`. But it still threw the same error.

Comment: @CodaChang Did you reload the console?

Comment: @CodaChang Can you update ypur question with the code what you are doing in the console along with full error message please.

Comment: @CodaChang Weird! Your code looks ok. Can you try opening another tab and open rails console and try.

Comment: Because there is a model called `order_item`, I typed `OrderItem `

Comment: It's really wired, and I push it on github  https://github.com/fifiteen82726/ShopCart

Comment: @CodaChang Update my answer. Please check :)

Comment: Oh god, Thanks. It's an embarrassing error, anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

In light of the comments, and to remove any doubt, here's what I'd expect from the *code*:

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user #-> the order belongs to user, so if order_items belong to order, they belong to user, right?
   has_many :order_items
   has_many :items, through: :order_items
end

#app/models/order_item.rb
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  #table name "order_items"
  #columns id | item_id | order_id | created_at | updated_at
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :order 
end
```

This is a typical [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship, as I'm sure you're aware.

--

Use Pavan's updated answer; the above should give you an idea as to the type of code you could expect from your models.

Comment: Now I just start create one to many structure, yeah I think I should modify it and use `has_many: through`. Thanks.