# Rails: NameError uninitialized constant on Database Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I have a model called "cube," which represents a collection of trading cards:

**app/models/cube.rb**

```
class Cube < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cubecards
  validates :name, length: { in: 3..30 }
end
```

As you can see, this model has a has_many relationship with cube_cards:

**app/models/cube_card.rb**

```
class CubeCard < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cube
end
```

While following [this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller) for help creating this relationship, the code references this form style:

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
```

For testing purposes, I just want people to input a number that corresponds with the card ID, so I have the following form:

**app/views/cubes/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @cube, @cube.cubecards.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= number_field(:card, :id, in: 1.0..8000.0, step: 1) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The problem is, `@cube.cubecards.build` is giving me trouble: rails throws an uninitialized constant error for `Cube::CubeCard`.

In other threads, I noticed that [plurality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41657286/8662829) has been [a common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32818631/8662829), but I can't find anything that would be a problem here.

I also noticed that [this fellow had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304421/ruby-error-uninitialized-constant-userrelationship?rq=1), but as far as I can tell the accepted solution does not apply to my code and the highly-voted solutions are about the controller. Here is my cube cards controller:

**app/controllers/cube_cards_controller.rb**

```
class CubeCardsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @cube = Cube.find(params[:cube_id])
    @cubecard = @cube.cubecards.create(cubecard_params)
    redirect_to cube_path(@cube)
  end

  private
    def cubecard_params
      params.require(:cubecard).permit(:card)
    end
end
```

To clarify once more, a `cube` can have **many** `cube_cards`.

I have also tried changing the plurality of `cubecard` to `cubecards`, adding the underscore (`cubecard` -> `cube_card` and `cube_cards`), and even the capitalization `cubecard` -> `CubeCard` and `CubeCards` to no avail.

The tutorial I'm following seems to skip right on through to the form without a single issue, so I know that, being a newbie, I must be making some elementary mistake, but I've been working for about a day now with no apparent solution.

I'm running this locally on a Windows 7 machine, with plans to migrate it to a web host once complete.

If it's helpful, I've posted the code [on github](https://github.com/dakotabuck/pokecube).

```
NameError in Cubes#show

Showing C:/Sites/pokecube/app/views/cubes/show.html.erb where line #25 raised:

uninitialized constant Cube::Cubecard

Extracted source (around line #25):

<p>
  Add a Card:
  <%= form_with(model: [ @cube, @cube.cubecards.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= number_field(:card, :id, in: 1.0..8000.0, step: 1) %>
  </p>
```

Also, my console spits out the following error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 69ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant Cube::Cubecard):
22:
23: <p>
24:   Add a Card:
25:   <%= form_with(model: [ @cube, @cube.cubecards.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
26:   <p>
27:     <%= number_field(:card, :id, in: 1.0..8000.0, step: 1) %>
28:   </p>

app/views/cubes/show.html.erb:25:in `_app_views_cubes_show_html_erb___540381856_44810532'
```

Comment: The code in your github repo has no migration for the Cube database?

Comment: @StephanePaquet, I added the file back and re-committed. I had moved it in order to drop the table. I had been using db:migrate to drop the cubecards table and re-add it, and I didn't want anything from the cube migration to get in the way

Comment: Post the actual error please. You are only showing what you think might be wrong rather than what is actually wrong. If the two were the same you wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: @jamesc I'm sorry for not posting it in the first place. You do make a compelling point. I've edited the original post with all the error info.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue. Unfortunately, I've fallen into a lot of the same trappings as people who have asked similar questions before me: the issue here stems from improper naming of my variables.

I was able to fix the code by changing `@cube.cubecards` to `@cube.cube_cards`

Additionally, in the params, I changed `:cubecard` to `:cube_card`

As it turns out, the only time I should have used cubecard as all one word is in the `Class` declarations at the beginning of each file. Every thing else references the table `cube_cards`, and as such should be spelled exactly in that manner.